# Acrobat PDF: Count non-empty text fields

Tags: javascript, pdf

Before I start, I am not sure if what I am doing is the proper way to approach it or if there is a better/easier way...

I have the following text fields: 
Resident[0]
Resident1[0]
Resident2[0]
Resident3[0]
Resident4[0]
Resident5[0]
Resident6[0]
Resident7[0]

occupancy_count

If the user types a name (Or whatever text) in the field, I need occupancy_count to intermediately and automatically count the total of fields that are not empty...

What I tried to do, to accomplish my task was to go to:
[Right-click] occupancy_count -> Properties -> Calculate -> Custom Calculation Script -> "Edit..."

**JS Script:**

```
    var count = 0;
    var field = "Resident";
    var numFields = 8;

for (var i=0; i<=numFields; i++) {
    var series = ( i === 0 )? "" : i;
    var v = getField(field + series  + "[0]").valueAsString;
    if (v!="") {
        count++;
    }
}

event.value = count;
```

However, the field occupancy_count is not doing anything >_<
Can you PLEASE help me figure out what am I doing wrong and get the field to count?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the text field [occupancy_count] -> Properties -> Calculate -> Custom Calculation Script -> "Edit..."

When the popup window shows up, copy and paste this javaScript code:

**JS Script:**

```
var sum = 0;
for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) {
    f = "Resident" + ( i == 0? "" : i ) + "[0]";
    if (getField( f ).valueAsString) {sum += 1;}
    }
event.value = sum;
```